# Removing rows from dataframe with multiple conditions

Tags: pandas

I am trying to remove rows from a dataset using multiple conditions but am recieving a few different errors. I have tried to populate a new df as well as drop from my existing df.

```
clean_df = df[df["assessment.Year_Built"] >= 1900 
              & df["assessment.Roof_Cover"] != 'Asbestos', '2', '3', 'Built-up', 'Roll Composition', 'Other', 'Tar and Gravel', 'Urethane', 'Wood', 'Wood Shake/ Shingles']
```

gives me the error - `TypeError: Cannot perform 'rand_' with a dtyped [object] array and scalar of type [bool]`

```
clean_df = df.drop(df[(df['assessment.Year_Built'] <= 1900)
                     & (df['assessment.Roof_Cover'] == 'Asbestos')].index)
```

The code above does not throw an error but does not actually drop anything from the df.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data? That would make it much easier to help troubleshoot

Answer (score 0):

try modifying your first line as follows. You were checking with not equal and then providing a list

```
clean_df = df[ (df["assessment.Year_Built"] >= 1900 )
              & (~df["assessment.Roof_Cover"].isin(['Asbestos', '2', '3', 
                                                  'Built-up', 'Roll Composition', 'Other', 
                                                  'Tar and Gravel', 'Urethane', 'Wood', 'Wood Shake/ Shingles'])) 
             ]
```

Comment: your .isin should be surrounded by should be surrounded by () correct?

Comment: yes @ArchAngelPwn, corrected. Thanks for pointing out

Comment: No problem, I know when you start getting all nested things slip through the cracks haha

Comment: yup, and its good when they slip so we know. The more frustrating part is when parenthsis are paired ....  but nested incorrectly :)